# Why does model for PostgreSQL not return values of linked tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have Asp.NET MVC5 app and try to write a model for PostgreSQL using `Npgsql` and `EntityFrameworkCore`.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;

namespace Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext() { }

        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GroupsRoles> GroupsRoles {get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<AspNetRoles>().HasKey(m => m.Id);
            builder.Entity<Groups>(b =>
            {
                b.HasKey(m => m.Id);
                b.HasMany(m => m.GroupsRoles)
                    .WithOne(gr => gr.Groups)
                    .HasForeignKey(g => g.GroupId)
                    .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
            builder.Entity<GroupsRoles>(b =>
            {
                b.HasKey(m => m.Id);
                b.HasOne(m => m.Groups)
                    .WithMany(g => g.GroupsRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(g => g.GroupId)
                    .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(sqlConnectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("AspNet5MultipleProject"));
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            updateUpdatedProperty<AspNetRoles>();
            updateUpdatedProperty<GroupsRoles>();
            updateUpdatedProperty<Groups>();

            return base.SaveChanges();
        }



        private void updateUpdatedProperty<T>() where T : class
        {
            var modifiedSourceInfo = ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(e => 
                e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified
            );
        }
    }

    public class AspNetRoles
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Groups
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<GroupsRoles> GroupsRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class GroupsRoles
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public AspNetRoles AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
        public Groups Groups { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All works except methods that returns values of linked tables. So, properties `Groups`, `AspNetRoles`, `GroupsRoles` are always `null`.
What do I doing wrong? How to mark it for `EntityFrameworkCore`?

Comment: Did you include them when you ran the query?

Comment: I can't find "methods that returns values of linked tables" in your code. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: I.e. `databaseContext.Groups.FirstOrDefault().GroupsRoles` return `null`. Although, after I called `databaseContext.GroupRoles.FirstOrDefault().Groups` it returns 1 item list (it's correct). I watched it in debugger.

Comment: I.e it returns single values correctly. But when I need to return `many` (collections) it will return it only after a request of an appropriate single value, otherwise - `null`.